# Find out IP address with Qt Mobility (on a s60 phone)

Tags: qt, ip-address, s60, qt-mobility

is there an easy way to find out phone's IP address with Qt Mobility? (In the context of s60 phone if that matters)

br, Touko

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works in normal Qt.. Apologies if it's a red herring.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QHostInfo info = QHostInfo::fromName( QHostInfo::localHostName() );
    QList<QHostAddress> l= info.addresses();
    for(int i=0; i<l.count(); i++) {
        qDebug()<<l[i].toString();
    }
}
```